# How to read Default.rule in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, rule

I have a project, in java, which is taken from site

[UBI REAL PROJECT](http://ubireal.org/)

Here in this Project, I found one file, named as ***Default.rule*** . I am unaware that how java files are can such extensions.

I cannot find where this class is called in project (After I extracted .class to .java).

So, If I see this file, its look like this in TextEditor

```
exLiving="Living Existence Sensor";
dvLight="Light";
LivingLamp1="LivingLamp1";
LivingLamp2="LivingLamp2";
LivingLamp3="LivingLamp3";
LivFan="LivingFan";
clock="Example";
curtain="Curtain";
camera="SurveillanceCamera";
component="MusicPlayer";
fan="Fan";

ruleset(0) {
    if( !exLiving.mah && !exLiving.Alice ){
        dvLight.SetPower(0.0);
        LivingLamp1.SetPower(1.0);
        LivingLamp2.SetPower(1.0);
        LivingLamp3.SetPower(1.0);
        LivFan.SetPower(0.0);
        clock.SetStatus(true);
        curtain.SetStatus(false);

        camera.SetPower(false);

        component.SetPower(false);

        fan.setPower(false);
    }   


if( exLiving.mah && exLiving.Alice ){
        dvLight.SetPower(1.0);
        LivingLamp1.SetPower(0.0);
        LivingLamp2.SetPower(1.0);
        LivingLamp3.SetPower(0.0);
        LivFan.SetPower(0.0);
        clock.SetStatus(true);
        curtain.SetStatus(true);

        camera.SetPower(false);

        component.SetPower(true);

        fan.setPower(true);



}
    if( exLiving.mah && !exLiving.Alice ){
        dvLight.SetPower(0.0);
        LivingLamp1.SetPower(1.0);
        LivingLamp2.SetPower(0.0);
        LivingLamp3.SetPower(0.0);
        LivFan.SetPower(0.0);
        clock.SetStatus(true);
        curtain.SetStatus(true);

        camera.SetPower(false);

        component.SetPower(true);

        fan.setPower(true);
    }
    if( !exLiving.mah && exLiving.Alice ){
        dvLight.SetPower(0.0);
        LivingLamp1.SetPower(1.0);
        LivingLamp2.SetPower(0.0);
        LivingLamp3.SetPower(0.0);
        LivFan.SetPower(0.0);
        clock.SetStatus(true);
        curtain.SetStatus(true);

        camera.SetPower(false);

        component.SetPower(true);

        fan.setPower(true);



}


}
```

Can anyone help me, I have given link of project. It is a simulation.

Comment: why do you think this is a java file, or related to eclipse? to me this seems to be some domain-specific language.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Java file but a *resource* file. You will see somewhere in the Java code a call like `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` on a `Class` or `ClassLoader` instance with the name of this resource to find that file and read/parse it using the Java I/O API.

Comment: okay dear, I got your idea, Let me covert all .class to .java, and then search for it. Thanks